# Add class to div if percentage hits 100

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to "addClass" once the progress bar hits 100%, but this isn't working. Any ideas? Thanks!

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8cjq2e2c/

```
$("#progress-plus").on('click', function () {
            $(".progress-bar").css("width", 100 * parseFloat($(".progress-bar").css('width')) / parseFloat($(".progress-bar").parent().css('width')) + 10 + '%');
            if ($(".progress-bar").width() >= 100) {
                $(".progress-bar").addClass("progress-bar-success");
            }
            else {
                $(".progress-bar").removeClass("progress-bar-success");
            };
        });
```

Comment: That code is only being run when your `progress-plus` element is clicked. There is no continuous polling going on here.

Comment: Once you click `$('#progress-plus')` you are setting the width of `$(".progress-bar")` to some dark magic value and then you check if its width is greater than 100 pixels. Is that what you want to do in the first place ?

Comment: So, on a click, the progress bar is updated and if it reaches 100%, you add a class, is that the intent?

Comment: @Malovich Yes, exactly. I'm wanting to add the class once it reaches 100%.

Comment: @PatrickQ I was just testing it inside the "click". Currently, it's just adding the class regardless of the "width" value.

Comment: `width() >= 100` is not checking for 100%, it is checking for `100px`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#progress-plus").on('click', function () {
            var targetWidth = parseFloat($(".progress-bar").css('width'));
            var parentWidth = parseFloat($(".progress-bar").parent().css('width'));
            $(".progress-bar").css("width", 
                ((100 * targetWidth  / parentWidth) + 10) + '%');
            if ( targetWidth / parentWidth >=1 ) {
                $(".progress-bar").addClass("progress-bar-success");
            }
            else {
                $(".progress-bar").removeClass("progress-bar-success");
            };
        });
```

This should clarify the matter.

The issue was that the syntax for the operators was ambiguous in your code, adding both the value 10 and the string '%', which can create values over 100% (Like, 9010%, to be exact) against which you are measuring to see if the width of the element is over 100px.

You want to measure the target against its parent with a simple increment of 10%.

Comment: Thanks! That works! Also, I appreciate the explanation. http://jsfiddle.net/8cjq2e2c/1/